# Two branches active at the same time?

Tags: git, github

I have a staging server which is usually used as a testbed for our development branch.  Recently we've added a new programmer who is working on new features.  We'd like to be able to host more than one branch on the server at the same time.

I think I'd like to be able to point our IIS at the hidden folder inside GIT, but is there any way to make all the branches visible?

At the moment I have a new site set up to a copy of the directory, but I have to manually copy the directory over when it is switched to branch B and then switch git back to branch A.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could simply have 2 clones of the repo on that machine in seperate folders to have 2 branches checked out simultaneously. Or, you could try out [git-new-workdir](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/)